# $a \le \|a\|$ in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann Algebra acting on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $a$ be a positive element of $M$. Then I want to show that $a \le \|a\|1$.
My attempt: Since $a\ge 0$, there exists an element $x \in M$ such that $a=x^*x$. I have to show that $\langle a \xi,\xi\rangle \le \langle \|a\|\xi,\xi\rangle$ for all $\xi \in H$. Now notice that,
$$\langle a \xi,\xi\rangle=\langle x^*x \xi,\xi\rangle=\|x\xi\|^2.$$
Now I am unable to proceed from here. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for you time and contribution.

Comment: I have impression that you want to show that $a\le \|a\|e,$ where $e$ is the unit.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes I mean this. $a \le \|a\| 1$ where $1$ is the identity

Comment: Then the conclusion is true for any self-adjoint element (operator) as by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$\langle a\xi,\xi \rangle \le \|a\xi\|\|\xi\|\le \|a\|\|\xi\|^2=\|a\|\langle \xi,\xi\rangle$$